# How to combine 2 :not class?

Tags: jquery

How would I define 2 `Not this class` ?

1 class :

```
$(document).on( 'click', '.item:not(.is-expanded)', function() {...
```

2 classes:

```
$(document).on( 'click', '.item:not(.is-expanded, .secondClass)', function() {
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work

```
$(document).on( 'click', '.item:not(.is-expanded):not(.secondClass)', function() {
```

Comment: `.item:not(.is-expanded, .secondClass)` will work too although it's not valid CSS selector.